# A vector of lists

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a chained hashtable for the first time . I thought of creating a vector of lists . So I declared a vector of list as private .

```
class HashTable{
public:
    HashTable( int ) ;
    void add( int k ) ;
    int remove( int k ) ;
    int find( int k ) ;
private:
    vector< list > t ;
    int n ; 
    int hash( int ) ; 
};
```

It is showing the following error :

\HashTable.cpp  [Error] type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template class std::vector'

Basically my question is List a type , so if we can declare vector of int so why cant vector of list be declared ?

Comment: You should change the title of your question to reflect the actual question. The title mentions deques but in fact you are using lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the template argument for list. It cant just be `list` it has to be list of something like `std::list<int>` (where int can be any other type but since all your other member functions use int, I used int in my example)

The following piece of code illustrates the problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector< std::list<int> > v; // this compiles 
    std::vector<std::list> v2;  // and this doesn't

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see below, all the compilation errors are from line 7 (the one with the missing template argument for list). [This was compiled on ideone](https://ideone.com/faT6GU)

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
prog.cpp:7:26: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
prog.cpp:7:26: error:   expected a type, got ‘list’
prog.cpp:7:26: error: template argument 2 is invalid
prog.cpp:7:30: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
prog.cpp:7:28: warning: unused variable ‘v2’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify what type the list should contain as elements. You can't just say "a list", you have to say "a list of some type T". The list template takes an argument, just like vector, so you have to say something like `std::vector<std::list<char*> >` . Be careful to leave a space after the first `>` if you're not using C++11, otherwise it won't work because it's parsed as the `>>` operator.